# html5 required attribute not working using angularstrap selectbox

Tags: angularjs

'required' attribute not working in angularstrap selectbox. need a red border if the value is not select from dropdown.

```
<button type="button" 
   class="btn btn-default"  
   ng-model="clearingType" 
   data-html="1" 
   bs-options="(clearingType.code+'-'+clearingType.description) as (clearingType.code+'-'+clearingType.description) for clearingType in clearingTypes" 
   placeholder="Please Select" 
   data-ng-change="getEffectiveDate()" 
   bs-select 
   focus-on="focusInput" required>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: use  ng-class="{ 'has-error' : }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for my problem using ng-class,

```
data-ng-class="{'hasError':hasError}"
```

and in css,

```
.btn.hasError{
    border:1px solid red !important;
}
```